# I need to style this text exactly like in mockup

Tags: html, css, sass

Future junior in training.

I need to style text just like in this image. That's the version for mobile.

[image]

It changes on tablet and on desktop.

[image]

I was thinking of just using a list but I don't think it would work on tablet/desktop version.

```
<div class="swiper-slide customer-review__slide">
        <img
          src="images/review-1-85.png"
          srcset="images/review-1-170.png 2x"
          alt="Satisfied customer"
          class="customer-review__picture"
        />
        <div class="customer-review__quote">
          <p class="customer-review__paragraph">
            Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In
            hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-review__dots">
          <svg width="8" height="8" class="customer-review__circle">
            <circle r="2" cx="4" cy="4" />
          </svg>
          <svg width="8" height="8" class="customer-review__circle">
            <circle r="2" cx="4" cy="4" />
          </svg>
          <svg width="8" height="8" class="customer-review__circle">
            <circle r="2" cx="4" cy="4" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <h3 class="customer-review__name">Emily, Los Angeles</h3>
      </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

I tried working with paddings and margins to no effect.

Comment: width is changing according to screen sizes and there is padding inside box

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to get the underline to extend to the edge of the container so you can use a repeating background to achieve a similar effect. You could modify this with some css custom properties to make the background and font size more flexible.

```css
.customer-review__paragraph {
  position: relative; /* creata a new containing block so the ::before pseudo element can be positioned in the right place */
  line-height: 2rem;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    #e0e0e0 0%,
    #e0e0e0 1px,
    #00000000 1px,
    #00000000 1rem
  );  /* Make a background look like underline */
  background-size: 100% 2rem; /*repeat it at the line height */
}

.customer-review__paragraph::before {
  content: "\201D"; /* unicode for a closing quote */
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0rem;
  top: 1rem;
  z-index: -1; /*position underneath the text */
}
```

```html
<p class="customer-review__paragraph">Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem. In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus.</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

I copied there script but add some changes like you can add span inside p tag and give p padding so inside lines have padding like above images in above script there is no padding but in your screenshots there was padding. you can't add padding directly inside p so I add span inside p also added background color to p class so it look exactly like your image [image]. it will look like this on mobile if you think you need more padding you can add it inside p.

```css
     .customer-review__paragraph {
            padding: 30px 50px;
            background: #fafafa;
            z-index:-2;
        }

        .customer-review__paragraph span {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            /* creata a new containing block so the ::before pseudo element can be positioned in the right place */
            line-height: 2rem;
            padding-inline: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
            background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,
                    #e0e0e0 0%,
                    #e0e0e0 1px,
                    #00000000 1px,
                    #00000000 1rem);
            /* Make a background look like underline */
            background-size: 100% 2rem;
            /*repeat it at the line height */
        }

        .customer-review__paragraph span::before {
            content: "\201D";
            /* unicode for a closing quote */
            font-size: 8rem;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            color: lightgray;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0rem;
            top: 1.2rem;
            z-index: -1;
            /*position underneath the text */
        }
        .customer-review__paragraph span {
        z-index:1;
        }
```

```html
<p class="customer-review__paragraph"><span>
            Nullam viverra consectetuer. Quisque cursus et, porttitor risus. Aliquam sem.
            In hendrerit nulla quam nunc, accumsan congue. Lorem ipsum primis in nibh vel risus.
</span></p>
```

Comment: Please provide details in your answer, not only code.

Comment: @Nisha are you just copying other contributor's answers?